# How to get the related objects in the Django rest API retrieve view?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here I have two models and have `Many-to-one` relation . In the `ListPackageGallery` class I want to list all the images uploaded to some package.

How can I query the images of some particular package here?

I am very new to django rest.So am I going the right way by using the `generics API view` for such cases ?

```
class Package(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name')
    package_desc = models.TextField()

class PackageGallery(models.Model):
    package = models.ForeignKey(Package, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='gallery')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='package_gallery')
```

serializers.py

```
class PackageGallerySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PackageGallery
        fields = '__all__'


 class PackageGalleryDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Package
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class CreatePackageGallery(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PackageGallerySerializer
    queryset = PackageGallery.objects.all()


class ListAllGallery(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PackageGallerySerializer
    queryset = PackageGallery.objects.all()


class ListPackageGallery(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = PackageGalleryDetailSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.gallery.all() #i got stuck here
```

urls.py

```
path('create/gallery/',CreatePackageGallery.as_view(),name='create_package_gallery'),
path('list/all/gallery/',ListAllGallery.as_view(),name='list_all_gallery'),
path('list/<slug>/gallery/',ListPackageGallery.as_view(),name='list_package_gallery'),
```

> Django Version:   2.2.7 Exception Type:   AttributeError Exception Value: 
>   'ListPackageGallery' object has no attribute 'gallery'

Comment: Hi! in you example `self.gallery.all()` `self` is instance of `ListPackageGallery ` class. Which is not what you expect I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `SerializerMethodField` to return the list of associated images:

```
class PackageGalleryDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = serializers.SerializerMethodField()    

    class Meta:
        model = Package
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_images(self, package):
        return [
            # Change this to meet your need e.g. `gallery.image.url`
            gallery.image.name
            for gallery in package.gallery.all()
        ]
```

Also, the `related_name` from `PackageGallery` to `Package` should be named e.g. `galleries` to have a better notion of the relationship as it's a many-to-one.

And you can drop the `get_queryset` method from `ListPackageGallery` as we don't need any filtering.

Comment: i return just `package.gallery.all()`  from the `get_images` and in the view I removed the `get_queryset` method  and provide `queryset=Package.objects.all()`  with this i got error  `Exception Value: 
Object of type PackageGallery is not JSON serializable`

Comment: @HelloWorld Exactly. You need something that is JSON serializable; in my example I've used the `pk` attribute of each instance, you can use filename e.g. but you must use something that is serializable.

Comment: i didn't get what should use when i just did `gallery.image` it throws `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte` and with pk  `'ImageFieldFile' object has no attribute 'pk'`

Comment: this solution will make N queries to your database, 
`N=number of image gallery rows connected to package`

Comment: @Mehran It definitely won't. The reverse model manager fetches all the fields of the related model in one query.

Comment: @heemayl oh yes it won't since you're showing only one package. thanks!